# How to return different future types in scala for a method

Tags: scala, future

Hi I am new to scala and I am stuck in a place as explained belore.

```
    def saveVariable(mappings: Seq):Future[SomeClass] = 
     if(mappings.nonEmpty) {
      // a method is called that return a Future[SomeClass] 
     } else Future.sucessfull(()) // need to return a empty future or
```

In the else part I do not want to do anything. I want to do an action only if mappings is nonEmpty.

But if I do something like this, obviously compiler complain that return type does not match for else part.

How can I solve this problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your user, how should he / she use the result of `saveVariabl` if it may be ***either*** `SomClass` or `Unit`? You have to make explicit that behavior, and for that reason [`Either[L, R]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) exists.

```
def foo[T](mappings: Seq[T]): Future[SomeClass] =
  ???

def saveVariable[T](mappings: Seq[T]): Future[Either[Unit, SomeClass]] =
  if(mappings.nonEmpty)
      foo(mappings).map(sc => Right(sc))
  else
    Future.sucessfull(Left(()))
```

---

Also, since a **Left** of just `Unit` is basically meaningless, consider using [`Option[T]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) as @ale64bit suggested.

```
def saveVariable[T](mappings: Seq[T]): Future[Option[SomeClass]] =
  if(mappings.nonEmpty)
      foo(mappings).map(sc => Some(sc))
  else
    Future.sucessfull(None)
```

Comment: Yes I did thought of using Option this way, but I get same issue. Compiler complain return type does not match. def saveVariable(mappings: Seq): Future[Some[SomeClass]] is method definition. In else part I return Future.successful(None). Compiler complains that its expect Future[Option[SomeClass]] where as you provide Future[None.type]

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal The return type should be `Future[Option[SomeClass]]` not `Future[Some[SomeClass]]`.

Comment: Ahhhh..my bad...Thanks for correcting this. I missed it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`Future.sucessful(())` has type `Future[Unit]` (because `()` has type `Unit`), which doesn't match the return type `Future[SomeClass]`. You are not providing `SomeClass`, so you would need to return `Future.successful(new SomeClass())` or something like that, that actually has the expected type.

If you want to return a value that is sometimes missing, consider returning `Future[Option[SomeClass]]` instead and in the else branch you can return `Future.successful(None)`. However, you will need to wrap the return value with `Some()` for the other case.

Comment: Yes I did thought of using Option this way, but I get same issue.
Compiler complain return type does not match.

def saveVariable(mappings: Seq): Future[Some[SomeClass]] is method definition.

In else part I return Future.successful(None).

Compiler complains that its expect Future[Option[SomeClass]] where as you provide Future[None.type]

Comment: `Some` and `None` are subtypes of `Option[T]`. See: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/d6FSpTd/0 as an example.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I figured. Bad of me to oversee this.